# Как отличить публицистический стиль речи от художественного?

Tags: стилистика

Я знаю отличительные признаки каждого стиля. Я умею отличить законченный текст публицистического стиля от текста стиля художественного. Вопрос касается текстов на ЕГЭ по русскому языку. Там даны отрывки из текстов, часто в сжатом виде. Если текст представляет собой рассказ из жизни героя, как ребенку, не читавшему этот текст полностью, определить, это отрывок из рассказа (стиль художественный) или это отрывок из воспоминаний писателя (понятно, он будет очень похож на художественный текст, но стиль -то уже не художественный). Можно говорить о так называемом художественно-публицистическом стиле речи. Но - при написании комментария к проблеме нужно четко разделять - говорим ли мы об авторе или о герое текста.

Answer (score 2):

Ларf, но ведь никто же не заставляет в комментарии определять стиль. Есть нейтральное слово "автор". Иногда это явно автор-рассказчик,иногда автор-повествователь, иногда автор произведения совпадает с героем (когда от первого лица и это явно писатель вспоминает о себе), иногда нет.От учеников никто не требует такой уж глубины, но чаще сразу видно, совпадает автор и герой или нет. Тогда лучше сказать "рассказчик".Вот в "Судьбе человека" есть автор - Шолохов, он же повествователь, а есть рассказчик А.Соколов, он же герой. Если ученики видят это и не путают - всё, этого достаточно.

Comment: Спасибо. В "Судьбе человека" все понятно. Если бы везде было так. Если Вы не против, когда я "споткнусь", обращусь к Вам на почту?

Comment: Конечно, буду рада . Вот только 3 дня меня не будет дома, а потом -  с удовольствием